# Solve the congruence $x^2=x \mod (2 \cdot 3)^2. $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How  to solve  the congruence $x^2=x \mod (2 \cdot 3)^2? $ Using brute  forse it is easy to show that $x=0,1,9,28.$ But  how to get the result by calculation?

Comment: Hint: use Hansel lemma.

Comment: yes, of cource, I need solution from $\mathbb{Z}_{36}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the equation into the coprime factors of 36:
$x(x-1)=0\pmod{2^23^2}$ will happen if $x(x-1)=0\pmod{2^2}$ and $x(x-1)=0\pmod{3^2}$.
$x=0,1\pmod4$ and $x=0,1\pmod9$.
There are four solutions:
$x=0\pmod4,x=0\pmod9$;
$x=0\pmod4,x=1\pmod9$ and so on.

Comment: In your last line you mean $x = 1$ (mod $4$) I suppose.

Comment: No, $x=1\pmod4$,$x=0\pmod9$ is the third line.